# iPhone Provisioning: The app was not installed because the signer is not valid

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store, provisioning

I have an iPhone app that was handed to me. I deleted all of the existing certificates & provisioning profiles and created them from scratch. I believe I have set everything in the Provisioning Portal correctly:

1. Distribution Certificate created
2. Devices with correct UDID's added
3. Ad-Hoc Provisioning file created with associated devices

I was able to successfully build & Archive my application. When I save it as a *.ipa and drag that and the *.mobileprovision file into iTunes everything is good, until my phone is syncing.

At that point I get an `iTunes Sync: Failed to Install error`. Other testers get the error: `The app was not installed because the signer is not valid`

I am not sure how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was correct, except for the final stage where I am given the save options. The profile matched my Distribution profile, but for the wrong app. It just defaulted to one of them. I had to manually change it to the Ad Hoc Distribution I was building for. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have received that error because I had created my .ipa file with the ad hoc provisioning profile BEFORE I added the devices. Are you sure that you are using the most recent provisioning profile when you create the ipa? You may need to check which scheme you are using and verify its right

Comment: Yes, the devices have been added to the ad-hoc. I am checking my scheme, and Archive is set to Release. Is this correct?

Comment: Edit: I didn't see you already figured it out, but this may help someone else out... Perhaps your release scheme is not using the provisioning profile but another. this tutorial shows how to make a new scheme to match adhoc... http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Answer (score 0):

This question was not resolved by the above suggestions, however we were able to fix it by removing the entitlements from the build.

This problem happened while working on an old app we were updating. No jailbreaking, just an ad hoc .ipa sent over email between team members.  All provisions were correct.

We were able to figure out the issue was entitlements by trying to install using "iPhone Configuration Utility" instead of iTunes. That gave us the actual error message which was easy to fix.

Debugging this issue was easier than with iTunes. It also has better UI for installing ad hoc builds. I recommend you try it here:

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27986/apple-iphone-configuration-utility

Answer (score -1):

i already  face this , finnaly i found,.

If Your Certificates, Provisoning Profiles then & the ipa is generated,,

so there is no problem in your ipa File,

But Problem in Specific Device in which you are try to insalled,,
If Your Device is JailBroken Then Easily iTunes cab Install ipa,,

But If Not Then You Have To Register/Add device to 
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
->Procsoning Profile -> Devices

Then & Then Ipa File Is Installed